# Binding this to be the checkbox I clicked in the ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code (forgive the script tags in the html.erb):

```
<div class="lists">
  <h1>Your Todo Lists</h1>
    <% @lists.each do |list| %>
      <div id="list">
        <%= list.title %>
        <% list.items.each do |item| %>
        <div class="item-list">
          <%= form_for :item, url: item_path(item), method: :post, html: { class: "item-box" } do |f|%>
            <%= f.label item.title %>
            <%= f.check_box item.id %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var changeDom = function(itemRow) {
      itemRow.closest(".item-list").remove()
      // $("complete-list").append(this)
    }

    var itemList = $(".item-list")
    itemList.find(":checkbox").on("change", function(box){
      var box = $(this)
      var item_number = parseInt(box[0].name.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)[0])
      $.ajax( { type: "PUT",
          url: "items/" + item_number,
          data: { id: item_number },
          success: function(text) {
            debugger;
            changeDom(this.closest(".item-list"))
          }
        });
      })
    })
</script>
```

In my success callback where I have the debugger... this appears to be the ajax object (it has a url path and data), but I want "this" to be the checkbox that I clicked. What do I do? I tried bind(this) in places where I thought it should be ... but nothing seemed to work. Basically, I am trying to remove the checkbox's row from the DOM and append it elsewhere on the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.closest(".item-list")
```

to

```
box.closest(".item-list")
```

Comment: @Jwan622 it wasn't :) do not forget to mark as the correct answer :)

Comment: You literally answered too quickly... You need to give me 3 more minutes.